# How Do I Pass Additional Parameters in Rails from Controller to Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to pass an additional field, say item_id into these line of codes (both controller and model):

```
# transactions_controller.rb (controller)
@transaction = Transaction.new(app_token: params[:token])

# transaction.rb (model)
def app_token=(token)
    write_attribute(:app_token, token)

    # I want to add a few more lines of code here so that I can manipulate item_id
end
```

That means, I would like my item_id to be passed from the controller to the model so that I can manipulate it do some customization within the model.

What would be the best way in order to do as such (based on the code above)?

===Updated as of 1-Sep-2014 for further details===

I have an association of cart and transaction in which cart has_many transactions and transaction belongs_to cart; below is the controller;

```
# transactions_controller.rb (controller)
def new
  @transaction = Transaction.new(app_token: params[:token])
end
```

While the method below is in the model:

```
# transaction.rb (model)
def app_token=(token)
    write_attribute(:app_token, token)

    # I want to add a few more lines of code here so that I can manipulate cart.id
end
```

What I would like to achieve here is to pass in the cart.id into the method of app_token which is located in transaction.rb. Please note that this cart.id is not meant to be saved into the database which I can easily do it via the create method through build, but rather this cart.id is used to be passed into the method to invoke other methods which is located within app_token method which sits in the transaction.rb model. The reason why I am doing this is because, the service which I am communicating with returns a token and I would like to hold the token and perform another method which requires the cart.id to be in.

Thus, I just would like to understand, based on the given format of the controller and model above, what is the most recommended manner to pass in this cart.id into the app_token method which sits in the transaction.rb model which I would want to use for other functions within the method?

Thank you!

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Do you want to pass arbitrary data elements when initializing a model instance?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @infused, I have edited the question to provide further clarity. Let me know if it is alright? Sorry for the confusion caused if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an association of cart and transaction in which cart has_many transactions and transaction belongs_to cart

Since that's the case and you already have a cart object, in your controller just instantiate the transaction from the cart:

```
transaction = cart.transactions.build app_token: params[:token]
transaction.save
```

`cart_id` will then be available to all the instance methods in the model, so there is no need to extend `app_token=` with additional logic unrelated to the app_token. Instead, take advantage of ActiveRecord callbacks. For example, you could use a `before_save` callback to implement your logic:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart
  before_save :do_something_with_cart

  def do_something_with_cart
    # I want to add a few more lines of code here so that I can manipulate cart_id
  end
end
```

If for some reason a callback does not fit your use casae, call the custom method directly in the controller:

```
transaction = cart.transactions.build app_token: params[:token]
transaction.do_something_with_cart
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! I ended up using the build method as suggested and without using the save method into ActiveRecord ; once the transaction object is built, I call the method in the Model to perform the necessary functions which I would like it to do!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to override *app_token=*

```
# transactions_controller.rb (controller)
@transaction = Transaction.new(app_token: params[:token], item_id: params[:item_id])
@transaction.save
```

Comment: thanks for highlighting! I just want to pass the data from the controller to the model method as per my ques above and this has nothing to do with saving to the database; thanks again for assisting!

Answer (score 1):

**Attribute**

It will mainly depend on whether you have `item_id` set up as an attribute, either virtual or in the database.

If you have an associative `foreign_key` set up already, you'll be able to discount what I'm going to write, but in case you haven't, you should consider the following:

```
#app/models/transaction.rb
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :item # -> expects item_id by default
end
```

If you don't have an association set up (and hence no attributes), you'll want to use [attr_accessor](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor) to create a virtual attribute:

```
#app/models/transaction.rb
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :item_id
end
```

---

**Params**

Passing attributes in Rails 4 is actually the least of your concerns - you can pass as many attributes through your routes as you wish. The problems occur when you try and match the items with your db objects (hence my recommendation above)

If you want to pass the `item_id` attribute, you'll just have to ensure it's set in your view. This is either done with your `routes`, or by passing it in your form:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :items
  resources :transactions #-> domain.com/items/:item_id/transactions/new
end
```

This would allow you to pass the `item_id` you wish (which will load in your controllers as `params[:item_id]`. You can also use the following:

```
#app/views/transactions/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @transaction do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :item_id %>
   <%= f.text_field :token %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will give you the ability to send the two different attributes to your controller, which can then populate as follows:

```
#app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @transaction = Transaction.new
   end

   def create
      @transaction = Transaction.new transaction_params
      @transaction.save
   end

   private

   def transaction_params
      params.require(:transaction).permit(:item_id, :token)
   end
end
```

It must be noted the `form` method will only be viable if you have the attribute defined in your model - either in the database, or virtual (with `attr_accessor`)

Comment: Thanks Rich; What I am attempting to achieve is more on passing of data from the controller to the model method based on the given code (as shown in the e.g above); the item_id which I used is just an example and has nothing to do with any association though; thanks again! :D